# Opening files on Android using Cocos2d-x api

Tags: c++, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I am having difficulty opening a file with cocos2d-x FileUtils in an android project. I am using Cocos2d-x v2.2.3 and the create_project.py to set up my project structure. There is a folder called Resources that contains some HelloWorld png's. I would like to add other files to this folder and then perform read operations with standard file stream operations. However, opening the file fails when running on the Android emulator. I have tried using CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getWritablePath() and then appending the name of the file. What is the correct way to use Cocos2d-x to open files on android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder Resources contains files for which the app has only a read access. 
To get the correct path to these files use:

```
string yourFilename = "hello.txt"; // only (relative path+) filename here, no absolute path!
string fullPath = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->fullPathForFilename(yourFilename.c_str());
```

Open the file using `fullPath`!

The routine  searches in a number of paths which can be extended.
See description of `CCFileUtils::fullPathForFilename()`

To define the search paths and the search order write something like:

```
vector<string> searchPaths;
searchPaths.push_back("1st_path");
searchPaths.push_back("2nd_path");
searchPaths.push_back("3rd_path");
CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->setSearchResolutionsOrder(searchPaths);
```

For Android apps the Resource folder is already part of the search paths, so no need to add it here.

To see the different paths try:

```
CCLOG ("full path: %s", fullPath.c_str());
CCLOG ("writable path: %s", CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getWritablePath().c_str());
```